# Interface IP conflict after dropbear-initramfs boot

Tags: networking, initramfs

I have a system with an encrypted root. I have installed dropbear-initramfs and am able to SSH in and unlock root and boot fine. However once I boot I end up with both eth0 and br0 with the same static IP and thus networking is not functioning.

Running `ifconfig eth0 0.0.0.0` gets everything going after boot, but I want to avoid having to load that in at boot as it feels very hacky. Looking for how to get initramfs to reset/cleardown/etc the eth0 interface to allow netplan to apply once the main system kernel boots.

The IP for initramfs is configured in /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf as follows `IP=”192.168.1.220:::255.255.255.0::eth0:off”`

Netplan config

```
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: no
  bridges:
    br0:
      interfaces: [eth0]
      dhcp4: no
      addresses:
      - 192.168.1.220/24
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 8.8.4.4
        search:
        - teese.net.au
  version: 2
```

I have tried setting IFDOWN=* in /etc/dropbear-initramfs/config to no avail.

Any tips would be appreciated.
Cheers

Comment: I end up running `ip addr flush dev $IFACE` after boot, which also feels hacky. Have you found a better solution?

Comment: My "better solution" was to set up a serial console connection from my raspberry pi that sits on top of it. Works for my needs and had a far less hacky feel to it. One thing to note I came across, needs to be an on motherboard COM port on the server as by default Ubuntu kernel is not built to work with USB serial (and I could not be bothered going a custom kernel build just to get a serial port working when I could just spend a couple of $$$ on a COM port Serial header)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Ubuntu 20.04 like me, you will find a file `/run/netplan/eno1.yaml` (or similar file) created after booting.

You can add a script under `/etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-bottom/` like this:

```
rm -f /run/netplan/eno1.yaml
```

to delete the IP address configuration you specified in `/etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf`

See this related question: [What is creating /run/netplan/eth0.yaml?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1228433/what-is-creating-run-netplan-eth0-yaml)

Comment: Thank you. Certainly appears to have solved my issue in my test box.

For those wanting my full fix it is as below:

```/etc/initramfs-tools/scripts/init-bottom/remove-eth0.sh```

```#!/bin/sh
rm -f /run/netplan/eth0.yaml
ip -f inet address flush dev eth0```

```update-initramfs -u```

Comment: Sorry above comment is formatted horribly and I can no-longer edit. So yeah obviously meant to be some line breaks in there.

Comment: Glad that helped! I too struggle on this issue for like 1 week.